Imshow, colormesh and contourf with MODIS data
my problem is that the pcolormesh make the right thing with interplation artefacts and imshow lose the lat/lon grid as shown in the image.


is there a way to get an mesh image without artefacts?
Here is my test code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

pwd_path = '/shared/sat_files/MODIS/'
files_for_myd = [
    'MYD04_L2.A2020172.1315.061.2020173154427.hdf',
    'MYD04_L2.A2020172.1320.061.2020173154612.hdf',
    'MYD04_L2.A2020172.1325.061.2020173155440.hdf',
    'MYD04_L2.A2020172.1455.061.2020173153643.hdf',
    'MYD04_L2.A2020172.1500.061.2020173154139.hdf',
    'MYD04_L2.A2020172.1505.061.2020173153403.hdf',
    'MYD04_L2.A2020172.1635.061.2020173154810.hdf',
    'MYD04_L2.A2020172.1640.061.2020173154608.hdf',
    'MYD04_L2.A2020172.1645.061.2020173154533.hdf'
]
files_for_mod = [
    'MOD04_L2.A2020172.1010.061.2020172192656.hdf',
    'MOD04_L2.A2020172.1015.061.2020172192633.hdf',
    'MOD04_L2.A2020172.1020.061.2020172192313.hdf',
    'MOD04_L2.A2020172.1150.061.2020172192858.hdf',
    'MOD04_L2.A2020172.1155.061.2020172192837.hdf',
    'MOD04_L2.A2020172.1200.061.2020173012747.hdf',
    'MOD04_L2.A2020172.1325.061.2020173012716.hdf',
    'MOD04_L2.A2020172.1330.061.2020173012718.hdf'
]

all_latitudes = []
all_longitudes = []
all_data = []

def read_data(file):
    hdf = SD(pwd_path + file, SDC.READ)
    data2D = hdf.select('AOD_550_Dark_Target_Deep_Blue_Combined')
    data = data2D[:,:].astype(np.double)
    lat = hdf.select('Latitude')[:,:]
    lon = hdf.select('Longitude')[:,:]

    # Attribute extrahieren
    attrs = data2D.attributes(full=1)
    fill_value = attrs["_FillValue"][0]
    scale_factor = attrs["scale_factor"][0]
    add_offset = attrs["add_offset"][0]

    # Daten verarbeiten
    data[data == fill_value] = np.nan
    data = (data - add_offset) * scale_factor

    return lat, lon, data

for file in files_for_myd:
    lat, lon, data = read_data(file)
    all_latitudes.append(lat)
    all_longitudes.append(lon)
    all_data.append(data)

for file in files_for_mod:
    lat, lon, data = read_data(file)
    all_latitudes.append(lat)
    all_longitudes.append(lon)
    all_data.append(data)

combined_latitudes = np.concatenate(all_latitudes, axis=0)
combined_longitudes = np.concatenate(all_longitudes, axis=0)
combined_data = np.concatenate(all_data, axis=0)
print(f"Latitudes shape: {combined_latitudes.shape}")
print(f"Longitudes shape: {combined_longitudes.shape}")
print(f"Data shape: {combined_data.shape}")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

extent = [combined_longitudes.min(), combined_longitudes.max(), combined_latitudes.min(), combined_latitudes.max()]
mesh = ax.pcolormesh(combined_longitudes, combined_latitudes, combined_data, cmap='jet', shading='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=1.0)

ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
ax.set_title('AOD 550 nm - Dark Target Deep Blue Combined', fontsize=16)
plt.colorbar(mesh, ax=ax, label='AOD 550 nm')

plt.savefig('aod_550_cartopy_plot.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()


The code combine both (Aqua and Terra) files. But a mean is currently missing. I think it is easier to discuss the problem without that.
